# Asp.net MVC Control execute 2 async task

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I want to check if this possible, I have an MVC Controller Action method (POST) which should have 2 parallel tasks, completing one of them should return the view based on the result from task that has completed.

Task is not aweb service which has asynchronous options. Assume its more like creating a bunch of file. I really want my task as simple as this.

```
private static string DoStuff(int sleepTime, string input)
{
      Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
      return input;
}
```

Task would be like - but i dont if this is correct or not because there is not 'await'

```
public async Task<string> DelayTimerCallAsync()
{

    string msgs = DoStuff(Convert.ToInt32(
                          ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DelayTimer"]), 
                          "Timeout");
    return msgs;
}
```

Let me know if my question is not clear or if you need more information.

From below update my 2 tasks are like this

```
public Task<String> DelayTimerCallAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        String messages = null;
        return DelayTimer();
     }, cancellationToken);
}

public Task<String> BlazeCallAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        String messages = null;
        return BlazeCall();
    }, cancellationToken);
}
```

How can I call them and use `Task.WhenAny(task1, task2)` ?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question before as well?

Comment: This is a little unclear, but from what I can see you'll be missing the point of tasks if you're not going to use `async`/`task<t>`. Might as well keep it inline or use a thread.

Comment: @AD.net I did ask this question before and didnt get any answers i tried to make it more clear i think.

Comment: Those 2 task will be of type async and return a string. some thing like...see my question updated.

Comment: So you want to run async methods from within a synchronous method (where you won't have `async`/`await`)?

Comment: You can wrap your `DoStuff` in `await Task.Run(() => DoStuff(...))`. Though I'm not 100% on what you're asking so maybe that's not useful?

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc aysnc task completion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285871/asp-net-mvc-aysnc-task-completion)

Comment: @siva.k: see below answer and my comment, i need 2 task which runs independently and completion of one will return like using Task.WhileAny(task1, task2)

Comment: @Praneeth from some quick testing you can't do this (assuming the `Task` library doesn't have a feature I'm not familiar with, which is possible). Using `await` will force all tasks to return before execution can return. Without using it you will return instantly. You may be better served by splitting these apart and firing two AJAX calls from the front end and which ever one of those returns you can abort the other and display your desired result. If that's useful I can post an answer on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question, however I'll take a stab at it.

Assuming you have "work" to do (that would normally run synchronously) but would like to wrap that in an async method, it would look sort of like the following:

```
public Task<String> DelayTimerCallAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  return Task.Run(() => {
    String messages = null;
    /* do work here (assign messages a value) */
    return messages;
  }, cancellationToken);
}
```

If you're looking to do the opposite (run a `Task` synchronously) you can do so easily as well. To help, here's a simple class that makes things a bit easier:

```
public static class AsyncHelper
{
    private static readonly TaskFactory taskFactory = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);

    public static void RunSync(Func<Task> func)
    {
        taskFactory
            .StartNew<Task>(func)
            .Unwrap()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }

    public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
    {
        return taskFactory
            .StartNew<Task<TResult>>(func)
            .Unwrap<TResult>()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }
}
```

You then have the ability to execute `Task` methods without `await`. Something like:

```
// (referencing DelayTimeCallAsync above:
String messages = AsynHelper.RunSync(DelayTimeCallAsync(CancellationToken.None));
```

Comment: First one is what i was looking for. But i will have 2 tasks which will start from the main class and completion of the either of them should return...Like using Task.WhenAny(task1, task2)